# Where/how can I download the complete Geo Location Targetting data from Adwords?

Tags: google-ads

Where/how can I download the complete Geo Location Targetting data from Adwords?

Is this publicly available?

Can I export it?

Grab it out of some Adwords Offline XML file?

Really appreciate your help

Update. I can find part of the data here. But not the reach. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting

[image]